# How to test an app for backwards compatibility?

Tags: android, testing, backwards-compatibility

If an app is targeted for a wide range of API versions (e.g. Android 5.1 to Android 9) and dev-phone got Android 7.1 installed, how is it tested to run on older devices?

What are the best practices to test that Android app runs across devices with different version of Android?

Comment: Check-out [androidx](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/) and [Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/). Ideally have an/many old device/s to test on. Emulation only goes so far...for example hardware acceleration cannot be emulated.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. If there are no specific hardware dependencies (such as BLE), you can try in different emulators.
2. Pay for a testing service and create automated tests, on platforms such as pCloudy.com or bitbar.com
3. Pay for the same testing services as above, but run manual tests. There are a lot of devices on those platforms, with older versions of Android.